# NET 6 API not working when inside a docker container

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

I'm making a CRUD basic API with the .net 6 basic API template for a class project and it was working perfectly when using it locally, so I tried to dokcerize it since I want to try and upload it to the cloud, but even when giving the enviroment variables for the ASPNETCORE_URLS it won't allow me to connect properly once in the container.

When I have SSL installed it either gives me a connection refused or SSL error, and if I take SSL off it'll give me a 404 error.

I'm a student and I'm just starting with .NET so it might be a dumb error.

The app works as intended when in the container since I tried making a compose with it and it made the migration just fine, I just can't seem to be able to access it from the browser, curl or postman
AppSettings.json

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;user=root;password=;database=alumnos"
  },
  "https_port": 443,  
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Dockerfile

```
#Build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /source
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "./CRUDAPI_ASIR/CRUDAPI_ASIR.csproj" --disable-parallel
RUN dotnet publish "./CRUDAPI_ASIR/CRUDAPI_ASIR.csproj" -c release -o /app --no-restore

#Serve

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal
WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=build /app ./

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

ENV server="mysql"
ENV user="root"
ENV password=""
ENV db="alumnos"

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CRUDAPI_ASIR.dll"]
```

Edit: Sorry about formatting errors, this is my first question and i'm kinda lost

Comment: Please provide code/configuration as text, not as pictures. We're software developers, we work with text editors, not with Photoshop. Text saves bandwidth. Text can be indexed by search engines, and text is easier to copy into an answer and then modify to provide you with a solution.